# PHP 5.3.4 deprecated functions emergency

Tags: php, codeigniter

The function `mysql_fetch_assoc` does not work anymore after I installed **PHP 5.3.4 on my wamp**. I have done everything that have been suggested in previous questions but nothing seems to be working.

I even tried editing the error reporting line on **php.ini** to:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

Unfortunately it is still not working. Please, any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is not working and what errors do you get?

Comment: There is no mention of mysql_fetch_assoc on the PHP 5 changelog page (http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php). Perhaps you could give us a sample of code showing your problem?

Comment: Use `errro_reporting(-1)` for developing.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've updated your PHP version, make sure that the mysql functions are enabled in your php.ini

There's a good chance that you are using a "new" version installed with the new version of PHP, and that it doesn't have the same extensions enabled. PHP has moved towards preferring the PDO calls over mysql calls.

Answer (score 0):

"deprecated functions emergency"

Wow that is one massive contradiction of terms. A deprecation message is lower than a warning, it really is just saying "by the way buddy, you should probably take care of this at some point". Most deprecated errors will warn you what you need to do and if not look up the function or feature in the manual and it will explain.

Looking at the manual for [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) you can see that it has not been deprecated, so your "not working" is inaccurate.

Post up the message you are getting or modify your php.ini settings to hide deprecated messages.

Comment: thanks for your help ,i simply unstalled the wamp 5.3 version and continued and installed 5.2.9 works well for me